# How to convert a recursive solution to bottom up or top down solution?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am solving this problem-

> Given a string consisting of a,b and c's, we can take any two adjacent
>   distinct characters and replace it with the third character. For
>   example, if 'a' and 'c' are adjacent, they can replaced with 'b'. What
>   is the smallest string which can result by applying this operation
>   repeatedly?

Now I have written the following recursive solution (far from efficient), but want to convert it to either top-down or bottom-up solution.

**Problem**: I am not able to come up with a tabular structure for memoization. Even though I have to output only the length of resulting string, how can I solve it without actually solving the problem. The strings are getting reduced, so how do I store them?

Any hint for DP solution or Memoization would be great!

**EDIT** Many people have come up with top-down memoization solution, please try bottom-up as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string reduce(string s)
{
    if (s.length() <= 1)
        return s;

    int k;
    char c = s[0];
    string min = s;
    for (k = 1; k < s.length() && c; ++k)
        if (s[k] != c)
            c = 0;
    if (c)
        return s;

    if (s.length() == 2){
        if (s[0] != 'a' && s[1] != 'a')
            s[0] = 'a';
        else if (s[0] != 'b' && s[1] != 'b')
            s[0] = 'b';
        else if (s[0] != 'c' && s[1] != 'c')
            s[0] = 'c';
        s.resize(1);
        return s;
    }

    for (k = 1; k < s.length(); ++k){
        string s1 = reduce(s.substr(0, k));
        string s2 = reduce(s.substr(k));

        if (s1.length() + s2.length() < min.length())
            min = s1 + s2;
        if (!s1.empty() && !s2.empty() && s1.back() != s2.front()){
            if (s1.back() != 'a' && s2.front() != 'a')
                s1.back() = 'a';
            else if (s1.back() != 'b' && s2.front() != 'b')
                s1.back() = 'b';
            else if (s1.back() != 'c' && s2.front() != 'c')
                s1.back() = 'c';
            s1 = reduce(s1 + s2.substr(1));
            if (s1.length() < min.length())
                min = s1;
        }

    }
    return min;
}

int main()
{
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    cout << reduce(input) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After every replacement do you start from begining or not? I meant if the string is `abbba -> cbba -> aba` or `abbba -> cbba -> cbc`??

Comment: @BharatSinha:We can apply this operation repeatedly at any place. we just want the smallest possible string. Since we need to consider all possible combination, DP comes to mind.

Comment: I would like to know if this operation is associative.

Comment: @ladaghini:of course it is associative.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by associative means in this context? I'm not sure how to apply it. Thanks.

Comment: @phant0m:Associative means that reduction can be applied on either side. Like, for "abc" `"ab"c = cc` and `a"bc" = aa` both are valid. But someone might interpret it some other way also.

Comment: Associative means, that when you have `a * b * c`, it doesn't matter whether you do `(a * b) * c)` or `a * (b * c)`. I don't see how this applies here. Have a look at the string `"abccabc"` you can either reduce it to `"cccccc"` and be stuck or you can reduce it to `"c"`.

Comment: @phant0m:You are right. I was not concerned with associativity at any moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit too lazy to think the problem through, but I'll give you an approach to memoization that often enough works.

Instead of recursing directly, introduce mutual recursion.

```
std::string reduce(std::string const &s)
{
    // ...
    string s1 = reduce_memo(s.substr(0, k));
    string s2 = reduce_memo(s.substr(k));
    // ...
}
```

where `reduce_memo` maintains a hash table, i.e. an `unordered_map`, mapping subproblems to their solutions.

```
// static is incredibly ugly, but I'll use it here for simplicity
static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> memo;

std::string reduce_memo(std::string const &s)
{
    try {
        return memo.at(s);
    } except (std::out_of_range const &) {
        std::string r = reduce(s);
        memo[s] = r;
        return r;
    }
}
```

When programming in C++98, use `std::map` instead of `unordered_map`.

Comment: +1 great explanation, but what do I use with gcc 4.6? map/unordered_map. Another concern, isn't it to costly (on space) a memoization? Can we have better?

Answer (score 1):

You can memoize your solution by storing the result of `reduce(s)` in a `map<string,string>`.

```
string reduce(string s, map<string,string>& memo) {
    if (memo.count(s)) {
        return memo[s];
    }
    // The rest of your code follows...
    memo[s] = min;
}
```

Comment: +1 that's quite understandable! but do I need to include `map` in signature, wouldn't it be better to make it global or something. Another concern, isn't it to costly (on space) a memoization?

Comment: @VinayakGarg You can certainly make it global, it does not matter much. I wanted to make it explicit in the example (and I made a mistake in declaring it as pass-by-value, too). The amount of space can be reduced if you use `map<string,int>`, since you're looking only for the length.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve the problem, but I noticed:

```
if (s.length() == 2){
    if (s[0] != 'a' && s[1] != 'a')
        s[0] = 'a';
    else if (s[0] != 'b' && s[1] != 'b')
        s[0] = 'b';
    else if (s[0] != 'c' && s[1] != 'c')
        s[0] = 'c';
    s.resize(1);
    return s;
}
```

doesn't work according to the problem statement:

> we can take any *two* **adjacent distinct** characters and replace it with the *third* character.

Consider the string `s = "bb"`. Neither `s[0]` nor `s[1]` are equal to `'a'`, which means the condition `s[0] != 'a' && s[1] != 'a'` will evaluate to `true` for the string `"bb"`. This goes for any string of consecutive characters of the same value, e.g. `"bb"`, `"cc"`.

Perhaps in the condition you can take the difference of the two consecutive characters, and check if they're non-zero.

Comment: Checking whether the difference is non-zero is equivalent to just checking whether `s[0] != s[1]`.

Comment: @larsmans Right. I was going to say to take the difference mod 3 which may perhaps help determine which character should replace the string. It doesn't work. Creating a lookup table should be fast and easy though.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever i have understood from the problem the solutions should be

length of the input - if all input characters are same like

```
aaaaa - 5
bbb - 3
```

and 1 in every other case.

Correct me if I miss some part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute minimum is `1`. However, the specifics of the string and replacement rules may yield between `1` and `n`, where `n` is the length of the string.

For the specific example, then the smallest possible is `n/2`, as you take 2 characters and replace them with 1 (which cannot be further replaced) so even if you had `"acacacacacacacac"`, the best possible case, you would still only achieve the factor of 2 reduction.

Comment: My program gives output `aa` for `acacacacacacacac`. Sorry if i did not state the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem in competitive programming workshop,
and indeed your proposed solution weren't fast enough.

My solution was creating such vector:

```
string s;
cin >> s;
int length = s.length();
vector<vector<int> > v(length, vector<int>(length)); // 2d array of size length*length.
```

where `v[i][j]` will be the minimal length the substring from `i` to `j` of `s` can get to.

Later all you have to do is fill this table in increasing size.
Hope that helped.

Comment: I also wanted to do something like this, but would the length suffice? Wouldn't strings be required to stored?

Comment: Instead of storing the string you should create some sort of transition table which represents the string.
Just to note, my problem had some cost for each letter combination, and I had to find the minimum cost to reduce the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
"a...a" (“a" * n) == > n
"b...b" (“b" * n) == > n
"c...c" (“c" * n) == > n
 any other ==> 1 or 2 with my greedy algorithm.
```

If we get 2 in this greedy algorithm, I can't prove it is the smallest result for the input string.

Greedy algorithm

```
while the last two is the same character { // the number of the same characters
    find the last replaceable pair         // at the tail will decrease until
        reduce them                        // it become 1
}

while find the first replaceable pair
    reduce them
```